# R slow to check developing package

Tags: r

I am developing a R package. Usually, checking process should spend around 5 minutes to complete. This week, I do not know why, the checking process takes around 20 minutes, after some small code changes. I've tried to run devtools::check() on multiple RStudio versions and on terminal, with the same result. I'm running R v4.03. Is normal this timing? Thanks

- top-left panel: devtools::check() process
- top-right panel: load package microbenchmark
- bottom panel: load package profiling

[image]

Comment: It looks as though loading the package takes about 63 seconds, which is quite unusual.  Does it try to connect to some external website during loading?  Maybe that's taking a minute to time out.

Comment: This package do not connect to internet

Comment: How long does it take to load if you just load it in a regular session, not in the check script?  It may be important that you set the environment variable `NOT_CRAN` to `true`, as when checking.

Comment: Using microbenchmark package, loading this package in a fresh session, takes 63 seconds. Screenshot edited with timing

Comment: It's too slow. I didn't have this behaviour last week

Comment: With Sys.setenv(NOT_CRAN = "true"), benchmark of devtools::check() is 1500 seconds

Comment: I've done the check process in a previous version of the package, from one month ago (all was fine there) and I'm having the same slow behaviour. Maybe it is R v4.03 version related (updated three days ago)

Comment: I've downgraded R to 4.02 version and check() the one month old package, and I have slow check() process too. I don't know what is happening then

Comment: I'd turn on profiling (in RStudio, choose the menu item), then load your package.  Profiling isn't very useful during a check, because it runs separate R sessions to do the checking, but just for loading, everything should be in the same session.  This might tell you where the time is being spent.

Comment: added loading profile plot to image

Comment: I don't find that plot very informative, but it does say that functions `.jinit` and `.jcall` were taking a long time.  Those are functions from the `rJava` package, and I'd guess anything involving Java would be going to the web to download stuff.  If you can figure out why they are being called now and stop it, I bet you'd see the slow loads go away.

Comment: You are right. My package depends on RBioFormats package from Bioconductor. This package depends on rJava package. I've noticed, time consumed to load RBioFormats changes if my computer is connected to internet. RBioFormats loads in 1.32 seconds when it's offline, and 61 seconds beeing online. I've opened an issue https://github.com/aoles/RBioFormats/issues/24. When I run check() offline, I get some warnings about URLs and it consumes only a pair of minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RBioFormats load time is fixed and not required to connect to internet, and problem solved